# Notepad++: How to Configure Notepad++ DBGp (Code Debuging Plugin) to Work With PYTHON?

Tags: python, plugins, notepad++

I've managed to make Python run on Notepad++ and what I need now is a debugging tool.I installed DBGP plugin but I'm unable to configure it to work as it always shows 'Disconnected' as in the picture. Anyone figure out how to make it work? Thanks!

The settings is shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: notepad++ is a nice text editor but not a real IDE. why aren't using a real IDE for python? You have pycharm for example, which comes with debugger out of the box.

Comment: Isn't DBGp a  PHP debugger? What makes you think it would work for Python?

Comment: @Dekel for some reason PyCharm takes forever to start and it is super complicated. I simply hate it. Notepad++ is super fast and much more user friendly

Comment: @martineau "isn't DBGp a PHP debugger?" I don't know! That's what I'm trying to figure out...conceptually if it works for PHP then it should work for Python?

Comment: Debuggers are usually very language specific (unless they are for assembly language), so I wouldn't think a PHP debugger would be likely to work for Python. Python has it's own standalone debugger, but it not integrated into Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update....I discovered that PyScripter IDE is almost as fast as Notepad++ to open and it can be customized to look exactly the same and it has great built-in debugging options. It worked right out of the box without any additional configuration. Highly recommended.